Appium Maven Test run using Jenkins locally
I tried to run Appium maven test locally using a Jenkins job.
First , I tried running the test using mvn commands on the command line tool and it worked properly.
After that, I tried to run the same test using a Jenkins job. The error given below.
Started by user KasunY
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\Kasun Yapa\Desktop\Etihad_Automation_2024\appium-pageobjectmodel-master
[appium-pageobjectmodel-master] $ cmd.exe /C "mvn test -DxmlFilePath=visitor_all.xml && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for TDDFramework:TDDFramework:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: Test:Assignment:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ line 72, column 16
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< TDDFramework:TDDFramework >----------------------
[INFO] Building TDDFramework 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for Test:Assignment:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.854 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-11T14:28:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TDDFramework: Could not resolve dependencies for project TDDFramework:TDDFramework:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact Test:Assignment:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Does anyone have an idea on this?

does the standalone build also emit the Warnings you showed in the output of maven? If yes, I would fix those first.
